# GoogleMap markers weird behaviour

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, infowindow

This is a strange one and I hope that someone can at least give me a direction to look in.

My Android application uses GoogleMap API v2.  In the app, I run an activity off OnClickInfoWindowListener on one of the markers.  In detail, when I click on the particular marker, an InfoWindow of that marker appears.  Next when I click on the InfoWindow, it launches another activity.

The problem is that when I return to GoogleMap from that activity, the particular marker which launched the activity, is not responsive.  By responsive, I mean when I click on it, I do not get an InfoWindow.  There is no such problem with the other markers.  To fix the problem, I either move or zoom on the map or click on another marker to show its InfoWindow, then the original marker works normally.  I cannot see any red stuff on the LogCat.

I also run the map off a ListView and there is no problem (that I can see).

Any suggestions on what to look at are very welcome!

Edit 1 :

This part is the InfoWindowClickListener setup ...

```
        // Set up info Window Click Listener
        googleMap
                .setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new OnInfoWindowClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker mkr) {
                        // Default open file
                        // menu option : edit file information
                        // menu option : delete
                        Log.d(TAG, "InfoWindow Click detected.");
                        final GeoFileData gfd = getFromHashMap(mkr);

                        if (editGeoFile) {
                            editGeoFile = false;

                            editFileInfo(gfd);
                        } else if (deleteGeoFile) {
                            deleteGeoFile = false;

                            deleteFile(gfd, mkr);
                        } else {

                            openFile(gfd);
                        }
                    }

                });
```

The openFile routine which launches the Activity

```
// Public and Routines used by the main loop
private void openFile (GeoFileData gfd) {

    int typeIndex = gfd.getTypeIndex();

    switch(typeIndex) {
        case 0 :
        case 1 :
        case 2 :
        case 3 :
            // Spen file by default
            Intent notePadIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), NotePad.class);
            Bundle b = new Bundle();
            b.putParcelable(MAIN_NOTEPAD_GFD, gfd);
            notePadIntent.putExtras(b);

            startActivityForResult(notePadIntent, SPEN_NOTEPAD_CODE);

            break;
        default :
            Log.w(TAG, "Unknown file.");
            Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.toast_unknown_file), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            break;
    }
}
```

The starting part of the launched activity

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_spen_notepad);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        inputGfd = extras.getParcelable(PreznsActivity.MAIN_NOTEPAD_GFD);
    }
    extras.clear();

    mContext = this;

    // Spen
    boolean isSpenFeatureEnabled = false;
    Spen spenPackage = new Spen();
    try {
        spenPackage.initialize(this);
        isSpenFeatureEnabled = spenPackage.isFeatureEnabled(Spen.DEVICE_PEN);
    } catch (SsdkUnsupportedException e) {
        if( SDKUtils.processUnsupportedException(this, e) == true) {
            return;
        }
    } catch (Exception e1) {
        Toast.makeText(mContext, "Cannot initialize Spen.",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        e1.printStackTrace();
        finish();
    }

    FrameLayout spenViewContainer =
        (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.spenViewContainer);
    RelativeLayout spenViewLayout =
        (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.spenViewLayout);

    // PenSettingView
    mPenSettingView =
        new SpenSettingPenLayout(mContext, new String(),
            spenViewLayout);
    if (mPenSettingView == null) {
        Toast.makeText(mContext, "Cannot create new PenSettingView.",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        finish();
    }
    // EraserSettingView
    mEraserSettingView =
        new SpenSettingEraserLayout(mContext, new String(),
            spenViewLayout);
    if (mEraserSettingView == null) {
        Toast.makeText(mContext, "Cannot create new EraserSettingView.",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        finish();
    }
    // TextSettingView
    mTextSettingView = new SpenSettingTextLayout(mContext, new String(), new HashMap<String, String>(), spenViewLayout);
    if (mTextSettingView == null) {
        Toast.makeText(mContext, "Cannot craeate new TextSettingView.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        finish();
    }
    spenViewContainer.addView(mPenSettingView);
    spenViewContainer.addView(mEraserSettingView);
    spenViewContainer.addView(mTextSettingView);

    // SpenSurfaceView
    mSpenSurfaceView = new SpenSurfaceView(mContext);
    if (mSpenSurfaceView == null) {
        Toast.makeText(mContext, "Cannot create new SpenSurfaceView.",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        finish();
    }
    spenViewLayout.addView(mSpenSurfaceView);
    mPenSettingView.setCanvasView(mSpenSurfaceView);
    mEraserSettingView.setCanvasView(mSpenSurfaceView);
    mTextSettingView.setCanvasView(mSpenSurfaceView);

    //
    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    mScreenRect = new Rect();
    display.getRectSize(mScreenRect);
    // SpenNoteDoc
    try {
        mSpenNoteDoc =
            new SpenNoteDoc(mContext, mScreenRect.width(), mScreenRect.height());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Toast.makeText(mContext, "Cannot create new NoteDoc",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        e.printStackTrace();
        finish();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        finish();
    }
    // NoteDoc
    mSpenPageDoc = mSpenNoteDoc.appendPage();
    mSpenPageDoc.setBackgroundColor(0xFFD6E6F5);
    mSpenPageDoc.clearHistory();
    // PageDoc
    mSpenSurfaceView.setPageDoc(mSpenPageDoc, true);

    initSettingInfo();
    // Listener
    mSpenSurfaceView.setTouchListener(mPenTouchListener);
    mSpenSurfaceView.setColorPickerListener(mColorPickerListener);
    mSpenSurfaceView.setTextChangeListener(mTextChangeListener);
    mSpenSurfaceView.setReplayListener(mReplayListener);
    mSpenPageDoc.setHistoryListener(mHistoryListener);
    mEraserSettingView.setEraserListener(mEraserListener);
    mSpenSurfaceView.setFlickListener(mFlickListener);

    // Button
    mTextObjBtn = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.textObjBtn);
    mTextObjBtn.setOnClickListener(mTextObjBtnClickListener);

    mPenBtn = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.penBtn);
    mPenBtn.setOnClickListener(mPenBtnClickListener);

    mEraserBtn = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.eraserBtn);
    mEraserBtn.setOnClickListener(mEraserBtnClickListener);

    mUndoBtn = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.undoBtn);
    mUndoBtn.setOnClickListener(undoNredoBtnClickListener);
    mUndoBtn.setEnabled(mSpenPageDoc.isUndoable());

    mRedoBtn = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.redoBtn);
    mRedoBtn.setOnClickListener(undoNredoBtnClickListener);
    mRedoBtn.setEnabled(mSpenPageDoc.isRedoable());

    mImgObjBtn = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgObjBtn);
    mImgObjBtn.setOnClickListener(mImgObjBtnClickListener);

    mAddPageBtn = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.addPageBtn);
    mAddPageBtn.setOnClickListener(mAddPageBtnClickListener);

    mTxtView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.spen_page);
    mTxtView.setText("Page" + mSpenNoteDoc.getPageIndexById(mSpenPageDoc.getId()));

    selectButton(mPenBtn);

    String filePath = inputGfd.getFileDirectory();
    mFilePath = new File(filePath);
    if (!mFilePath.exists()) {
        if (!mFilePath.mkdirs()) {
            Toast.makeText(mContext,  "Save Path Creation Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }
    }

    mSpenPageDoc.startRecord();

    File loadFile = new File(inputGfd.getFileDirectory(), inputGfd.getFileName());
    if (loadFile.exists()) {
        loadNoteFile();
    } else {
        Log.w(TAG, "File does not exist!");
    }

    if(isSpenFeatureEnabled == false) {
        mToolType = SpenSurfaceView.TOOL_FINGER;
        mSpenSurfaceView.setToolTypeAction(mToolType,
            SpenSurfaceView.ACTION_STROKE);
        Toast.makeText(mContext,
            "Device does not support Spen. \n You can draw stroke by finger",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

One of the returns for the activity

```
    private boolean saveNoteFile(final boolean isClose) {
    // file save
    // note file
    String saveFilePath = inputGfd.getFileDirectory() + File.separator;
    String fileName = inputGfd.getFileName();
    if (!fileName.equals("")) {
        saveFilePath += fileName;

        saveNoteFile(saveFilePath);
        if (isClose)
            finish();
    } else {
        Toast
        .makeText(mContext, "Invalid filename !!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
        .show();
    }

    return true;
}
```

and finally the destroy routine,

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    Log.d(TAG, "NotePad onDestroy()");

    super.onDestroy();

    if (mSpenNoteDoc != null && mSpenPageDoc.isRecording()) {
        mSpenPageDoc.stopRecord();
    }

    if (mPenSettingView != null) {
        mPenSettingView.close();
    }
    if (mEraserSettingView != null) {
        mEraserSettingView.close();
    }
    if (mTextSettingView != null) {
        mTextSettingView.close();
    }
    if(mSpenSurfaceView != null) {
        if (mSpenSurfaceView.getReplayState() == SpenSurfaceView.REPLAY_STATE_PLAYING) {
            mSpenSurfaceView.stopReplay();
        }
        mSpenSurfaceView.closeControl();
        mSpenSurfaceView.close();
        mSpenSurfaceView = null;
    }

    if(mSpenNoteDoc != null) {
        try {
            if (isDiscard)
                mSpenNoteDoc.discard();
            else
                mSpenNoteDoc.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        mSpenNoteDoc = null;
    }
};
```

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, bad grammar.  I don't run it off one marker, this applies to all markers.

Comment: It should be a logic problem some where , please share your code causing problem

Comment: Thanks for replying.  Just for the sake of argument, if it is a logic problem than how come there is no issue running off the ListView?  I've got no problems adding code but the thing is "where from"?  Where do you suspect the problem is in please?

Answer (score 0):

This is likely a bug in Google Maps Android API v2 itself.

I encounter it [in my app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=pl.mg6.android.maps.extensions.demo). When you open "Declusterification" demo, click on yellow marker with 10 in the center and a new marker (red default) appears in the same spot, this new marker cannot be interacted with to show info window without moving the map.

If you happen to figure out [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) for it, I suggest posting it on [gmaps-api-issues](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/list?can=2&q=apitype=Android2). I'll support it. If I do find simple example to show this issue, I'll also post an update here.

Comment: Hi, did you manage to get around the problem please?  I commented out nearly all the lines in the Activity's onCreate() leaving only the super.onCreate(), setContentView() and a mContext=this but the problem persists.

Comment: Figured a way around it.  I did a googleMap.moveCamera() to the same position.

Comment: @DanielWong That might be ok for a workaournd, but I'd rather have this fixed in the library. Can you share the minimalistic code that shows this issue?

Comment: Okay give me sometime.  Will comment again in this post once I've done it.

Comment: I've submitted the issue to google.  Here is the link to it. https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=6108&thanks=6108&ts=1385393564

Comment: Great. Will continue on this issue there.

Answer (score 0):

To close up this question.

GoogleMap markers exhibit the anomalies mentioned in this thread and currently the issue has been fed back to Google.  There are two apparent "workarounds" to the problem but how effective they are is not clear:

1st workaround : work within the limitations of .clear().  An activated marker cannot be deactivated with .clear().

2nd workaround : after returning from the activity, perform a camera update.  This apparently resets the activation of the marker.